# Persistence Framewoks

Tags: api, architecture, frameworks, persistence

I am trying to learn more about Software Architecture and right now I am looking for Frameworks for persitency. I am not really sure how you define Frameworks when you are an architect. I know frameworks for specific programming languages, do I have to consider them in software architecture as well or are there specific Frameworks for persitency in Software architecture? If yes can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start from fixing domain problems, then you can filter out requirements for the solution. in order to cater to those, select software stack. there you have to consider the constraint(cost/time) and resources(team competencies) you got. this process will lead to your final solution architecture.

ex: 
-> requirements -> suitable solutions -> situation -> framework

- financial system -> db(MySQL, oracle)/framework(NHibernate,Hibernate) -> client need oracle certification & team competent on java ->  Spring with Hibernate
- legacy java system upgrade with less rewite, use raw sql like ORM -> MyBatis
- a social network -> graph DB(neo4j,AWS-neptune) -> users will be from around the globe -> AWS-neptune
- CMS -> db(MySQL, PostgreSQL)/framework(Flask-SqlAlchemy,Rails-ActiveRecord,Laravel-Eloquent, Wordpress) -> can't wait, lets use existing one -> Wordpress
- store unstructured data -> MongoDB, DynamoDB -> we have so many ruby devs, data is more json like nested -> Mongoid ORM
- Android aplication -> sqlite, firebase -> need to sync realtime -> firebase
- store cache -> Redis, Memcached -> we do golang microservices -> go-redis
- to do analytical stuff -> PostgreSQL,spark, hive -> ...

hope you got the pattern